# $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z_{11})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{10}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The question is this:

Prove that $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z_{11})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{10}$.

---

I tried to construct a mapping from $f\colon\mathbb Z_n\to \mathbb Z_n$ and $f([k])=[ka]$ where $f$ is in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z_n)$ (I have proven that..)
But I still have no idea how to keep think along this idea. Maybe it is not helpful.I am not sure..

I also confused about is that, $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z_{11})$ is a group that has a bunch of mappings, and $\mathbb Z_{10}$ is a group. How can I have a mapping, that maps from a mapping to a element of group? 
How to understand about that?

Could you give some hints about this problem or help me better understand, if possible? 
Thanks!

Comment: You should try to prove directly that if $p$ is a prime, then $\mbox{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$. Somehow, it is easier, since it stresses out the key fact that $p$ is prime.

Comment: Sure julien, but it is harder to prove it for general $p$. I would only advice to show $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/n) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$ for general $n$. (Unfortunately again the wrong notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ here ...)

Comment: @TWeJ735, "How can I have a mapping, that maps from a mapping to a element of group?" --  $Aut(\mathbb Z_11)$ is a group under composition. Do you see why?

Comment: Yes I see that..

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $f: \mathbb Z_{11} \to \mathbb Z_{11}$ be an automorphism.

If $f([1])=[a]$ what is $f([2])$? What about $f([k])$?

Moreover what can $[a]$ be?

if $g[1]=[b]$ is another automorphism, can you see any connection between $f \circ g, a$ and $b$?

Comment: So f([2])=[2a], and f([k])=[ka]..

Comment: And fog([K])=[2kab]?

Comment: @TWeJ735 Are you sure about the $2$ in $2kab$? So, $f$ can be "identified" with the corresponding $a$, $b$ with $g$ but then composition of functions becomes multiplication in $\mathbb Z_{11}$..Does this tell you what the isomorphism is? Note that you get multiplication in $\mathbb Z_{11}$ but also that $a$ cannot be anything, it only be .....

Comment: Sorry..It is supposed to be [kab]..right?

Comment: So [a] have to be one of generators of Z11?

Comment: @TWeJ735 When is the function $f[k]=[ak]$ an bijection?

Comment: when f is in Aut(Zn)? I am not sure if that is the direction you want me go..

Comment: @TWeJ735 and for which values of $a$ does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Find the order of $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_{11})$. Show that an element in it has the same order. It follows that $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_{11}) \cong Z_n$ where $n = \left| \operatorname{Aut}(Z_{11}) \right|$.

Comment: n=10 since there are 10 generators in $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_{11})$

Comment: Then how to use this fact to show $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_{11}) \cong Z_n$?

Comment: @TWeJ735 If you find an element $\sigma$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_{11})$ with order $10$, it follows that this element is a generator of $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_{11})$ because the powers $\sigma^j$ are distinct for $0 \le j < n$. From there, it's clear that $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_{11})$ is cyclic.

Comment: @TWeJ735 There are not $10$ generators in $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{11})$. For example, the identity element does not generate the group. (Indeed, a group of order $10$ contains $10$ elements, including the identity, an element of order $5$ (why?) and an element of order $2$ (why?). These elements cannot generate the whole group on their own.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: An abelian group of order 10 is cyclic.

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Group?

Comment: Since 2 and 5 are relatively prime.

Comment: Then Z2 x Z5 is isomorphic to Z10?

Comment: I have no idea how to relate this to $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_11)$

Comment: First you have to show $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{11})$ is abelian group of order 10, then use the hint.

Comment: Although this is true, I do not see how it is helpful...

Answer (score 1):

We can use following,

1. $Aut(Z_{n}) \cong U(n)$ for every positive integer $n$,
2. $U(p^n)\cong Z_{p^n-p^{n-1}}$ for any odd prime $p$ and positive integer $n$.

Therefore, $Aut(Z_{11}) \cong U(11)$ and $U(11) \cong Z_{10}$.